# The input of my list changes, how do I correct this?

Tags: python-3.x, list, types

This is the beginning of my code:

```
mylist = input()
```

As Input I have:

```
In:   [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

but then they define :

```
mylist = '[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]'
```

How do I remove the '' ?

Answer (score 0):

to get a list either do

```
 mylist = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
```

ex input will be : `1 2 3 4 5` and output will be `[1,2,3,4,5]`

in your case do `mylist=eval(mylist)`

Answer (score 0):

> **Return value from input():**
>
> The input() method reads a line from input (usually user), converts
>   the line into a string by removing the trailing newline, and returns
>   it.

Because of that you have:

```
'[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]' #  <class 'str'>
```

We can use `ast.literal_eval()` here to evaluate the string as a python expression. It safely evaluates an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

```
mylist = input()
print (mylist)
print (type(mylist)) # <class 'str'>

import ast
mylist_ = ast.literal_eval(mylist)
print (mylist_)
print (type(mylist_)) # <class 'list'>
```

output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
<class 'str'>
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]
<class 'list'>
```